# PHP regEx help needed with /*<##> </##>*/

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling with regEx, but can not get it to work.
I already try with:
[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390778/php-preg-replace-comment-blocks), [online tool](http://www.softlion.com/webTools/RegExpTest/),

```
$text = preg_replace("%/\*<##>(?:(?!\*/).)</##>*\*/%s", "new", $text);
```

But nothing works. 
My input string is:

```
$input = "something /*<##>old or something else</##>*/ something other";
```

and expected result is:

```
something /*<##>new</##>*/ something other
```

Comment: You don't have a quantifier for the lookahead-masked `(.)` match-all. Therefore it would only accept one-character strings in your comments. Also just replacing with `new` will not reinstantiate the `/*<##>` comment markers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues that point out here, you have no capturing groups to replace the delimited markers inside your replacement call and your Negative Lookahead syntax is missing a [repetition operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

```
$text = preg_replace('%(/\*<##>)(?:(?!\*/).)*(</##>*\*/)%s', '$1new$2', $text);
```

Although, you can replace the lookahead with `.*?` since you are using the `s` (dotall) modifier.

```
$text = preg_replace('%(/\*<##>).*?(</##>*\*/)%s', '$1new$2', $text);
```

Or consider using a combination of lookarounds to do this without capturing groups.

```
$text = preg_replace('%/\*<##>\K.*?(?=</##>\*/)%s', 'new', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested:

```
$input = "something /*<##>old or something else</##>*/ something other";

echo preg_replace('%(/\*<##>)(.*)(</##>\*/)%', '$1new$3', $input);
```